# How to use Chai-jQuery's expect().to.match() assertion in Cypress? The BDD assertion with the same name gets used instead

Tags: javascript, cypress, chai

I want to use the [Chai-jQuery `.match` assertion](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Chai-jQuery):

```js
// from Cypress docs: 
// match(selector)  
expect($emptyEl).to.match(':empty')
```

But the problem is, that a [BDD Assertion](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#BDD-Assertions) with the same name exists:

```js
// from Cypress docs: 
// match(RegExp)
expect('testing').to.match(/^test/)
```

I want to use the first one, but I can't figure out how - each time the BDD assertion gets used instead and throws an error. For example:

```js
expect(cy.get('div')).to.match('#someId')
```

> match requires its argument be a RegExp. You passed: #someId

I tried passing many different things into the `expect()` call in hopes of triggering a different overload, but I always get this error.

So what do I need to do to use the Chai-jQuery `.match` aseertion?

Comment: @AlapanDas The `Chai-jQuery` `.match()` assertion tests if an element satisfies a css selectir. The BDD assertion matches if string matches a regexp. I am trying to use the `Chai-jQuery` assertion to assert if an element satisfies a css selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Cypress choses the `.match()` version from the ***type*** passed to the `expect()` part.

With this fragment

```html
<div id="someId">some text</div>
```

this will pass

```js
cy.get('div').then($el => {

  expect($el).to.match('#someId')  // $el is type object, 
                                   // so match will be from chai-jQuery

  expect($el.text()).to.match(/some text/)  // $el.text() is type string, 
                                            // so match will be from chai
})

// Same applies with .should() wrapper

cy.get('div').should('match', '#someId')

cy.get('div').invoke('text').should('match', /some text/)
```

Comment: That's it! I couldn't figure out know what the `$el` is supposed to stand for, and it's what I get in `then` callback. Thank you very much!

Comment: `$el` is just a variable name. the `$` is mainly used to denote a jquery element